# How to `chmod -R +w` with Ant, files and folders?

Tags: linux, ant, recursion, chmod

I'd like to do the equivalent of a `chmod -R +w foo/` in an **Ant** build script.

So far I'm using this:

```
<chmod perm="g+w">
   <dirset dir="${basedir}/foo">
   </dirset>
   <fileset dir="${basedir}/foo">
   </fileset>
</chmod>
```

Is there a neater way to write that to include files *and* folders *recursively*?

Comment: Damn, you're right. I removed my answer and investigate a bit further...

Comment: Solution: `<chmod file="${basedir}/foo/**" perm="g+w" type="both"/>`, I let you post it ;)

Comment: Well, I was coming back with the same solution. Thanks for letting me posting it :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following does work:

```
<chmod file="${basedir}/foo/**" perm="g+w" type="both"/>
```

Credits shared with the OP.

#### See also

- [Chmod Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/chmod.html)

Comment: @Wernight: The `type="both"` has to be used with `file=`. But the key was indeed the use of the `**`.

Answer (score 4):

To chmod one can use exec:

```
<exec executable="chmod" dir="${basedir}/foo" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="-R 0755 ." />
</exec>
```

[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923884/can-ants-recursive-chmod-compete-with-exec-in-terms-of-speed)

Comment: That would only work if the system as a `chmod` tool, i.e., on *nix not likely on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the gradle version :

```
task fixPermissions << {
    ant.chmod(dir:"$rootDir/foo", perm:"g+w", includes:"**/*")
}
```